# How to initialize (declare) an array in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, initialization, declaration

I am absolute beginner on TypeScript. I want to initialize an array of numbers in TypeScript by "for" loop as you see in the following:

```
 public hours: number[];
 constructor() {
   for (let i: number = 1; i < 25; i++) {
      this.hours[i] = i;
    }
  }
```

I get an error: Cannot set property '1' of undefined.
Could you please help me?

Comment: In the constructor: `hours = new Array()`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This line:

```
public hours: number[];
```

Does not create a new array, it only declares it.
If you compile this code:

```
class MyClass {
    public hours: number[];

    constructor() {
        for (let i: number = 1; i < 25; i++) {
            this.hours[i] = i;
        }
    }
}
```

You get:

```
var MyClass = (function () {
    function MyClass() {
        for (var i = 1; i < 25; i++) {
            this.hours[i] = i;
        }
    }
    return MyClass;
}());
```

As you can see, `this.hours` isn't being assigned.

So you need to do this:

```
constructor() {
    this.hours = [];

    for (let i: number = 1; i < 25; i++) {
        this.hours[i] = i;
    }
}
```

Or:

```
public hours: number[] = [];
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Thank you, i was stuck at this.

Answer (score 1):

hours isn't set to any value. You can create a new array in the constructor, or set hours to an empty array:

```
public hours: number[] = [];
constructor() {
   for (let i: number = 1; i < 25; i++) {
      this.hours[i] = i;
   }
}
```